# EDIT | Is it possible to send (transfer, request) ADA using just Javascript?

Tags: wallet, javascript

Using just HTML / PHP / Javascript and cardano-serialization, I have the connect wallet working. It shows the balance and stake address. So I have gotten that far.

My question is, how can I request the connected wallet for a chosen amount of ADA?

I do not want to use Mesh or any of those, just using Javascript.

Any and all input greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:** I am getting a lot of errors, can anyone tell me what else I can do to make this work correctly?

```
<script type="module">

import { Blockfrost, Lucid } from "https://unpkg.com/lucid-cardano@0.10.2/web/mod.js"; // NPM

const lucid = await Lucid.new(
  new Blockfrost("https://cardano-preview.blockfrost.io/api/v0", 
"mainnet..."),
"Preview",
);

// Assumes you are in a browser environment
const api = await window.cardano.nami.enable();
lucid.selectWallet(api);

const tx = await lucid.newTx()    

 .payToAddress("addr...", { lovelace: 5000000n })
  .complete();

const signedTx = await tx.sign().complete();

const txHash = await signedTx.submit();

console.log(txHash);

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using Lucid for this:

```
import { Blockfrost, Lucid } from "lucid-cardano"; // NPM

const lucid = await Lucid.new(
  new Blockfrost("https://cardano-preview.blockfrost.io/api/v0", "<projectId>"),
  "Preview",
);

// Assumes you are in a browser environment
const api = await window.cardano.nami.enable();
lucid.selectWallet(api);

const tx = await lucid.newTx()
  .payToAddress("addr...", { lovelace: 5000000n })
  .complete();

const signedTx = await tx.sign().complete();

const txHash = await signedTx.submit();

console.log(txHash);
```

This piece of code (from the [lucid](https://github.com/spacebudz/lucid) github page) selects a wallet injected in the browser (in this case Nami) and creates a transaction using Lucid. It is quite easy to use and well documented!

Comment: I tried using this, can you look at the code i submitted and let me know what to change/add? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be looking for this. https://cardano.stackexchange.com/a/7657/7159

Here is the official documentation.
https://developers.cardano.org/docs/get-started/cardano-serialization-lib/generating-transactions/